# В JS происходит изменение свойства display на block, а нужно flex. Команда есть, а js её не выполняет

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать переход между блоками путём скрытия и показа их пользователю. Есть блок "приветствия", на которой ссылки. По нажатии на ссылку скрывается этот блок и появляется блок с необходимым контентом, но при это в атрибуте, нужного блока, style свойство display заменяется с none на block, хотя в js прописано `document.getElementById('mem1').style.display = 'flex';`

Код обработки:

```html
<div class="lvlChanger" id="lvlChanger" style="display: block;">
  <form class="info">
    Игра "Найди пересонажа" схожа с всемиизвестной игрой "Найди пару". Вы должны совместить элемент и персонажа, который этим элементом владеет.<br>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('mem1').style.display = 'flex'; document.getElementById('lvlChanger').style.display = 'none'; " id="first">Первый</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('mem2').style.display = 'flex'; document.getElementById('lvlChanger').style.display = 'none';" id="second">Второй</a>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="mem1" id="mem1" style="display: none;">
  random text with example
</div>
```

В css у блока с id "mem1" у display стоит "flex". При обработке нажатия, по итогу, вместо "flex" в инспекторе отображается "block".

Comment: А точно block? Попробуйте вот так вывести в консоль:
let first = document.getElementById('first');
first.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
console.log(mem1.style.display)
})

Comment: В консоль выводится block. Так что точно он

Comment: Приложите срин. У меня везде выводится флекс. И в консоли и в инспекторе.

Comment: Смотрите следующий ответ

Comment: В сниппете флекс добавляется а не блок если нажать на Первый

Comment: Через инспектор если менять block на flex всё получается и элементы встают как надо, но без этого не выходит. Пытался через jquery там то же самое получается.

Comment: @LinarBakeev У меня ваш код добавляет flex а не block. запустите сниппет и посмотрите в браузере

Comment: Судя по вашему скрину проблема не в этих строчках кода, так как в снипете работает так как ожидалось (добавляется flex а не block) где то у вас в другом месте другой скрипт ставит block

Comment: @Greg--, в том то и прикол, что в сниппете работает как надо, а на странице получается block

Comment: @Greg--, спасибо. Нашёл. Вы были правы.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первом скрине mem1, имевший display none стал block и в консоли тоже

```css
.mem1{
    width: 650px;
    height: 650px;
    margin:  auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Код выше - свойства, описанные в css файле